# How to convert Unicode character to symbol/special character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a sentence 'Hello \u0028 Hi \u0029' that contains few unicode character.My requirement is if any sentence contains unicode character it will be converted into special character for ex- 'Hello ( Hi )'.I have already tried but it is not working.Please find below code

### 1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var str= 'Hello \\u0028 Hi \\u0029';
   var res= str.replace(/&#([0-9]{1,4});/gi, function(match, numStr) {
        var num = parseInt(numStr, 10); // read num as normal number
        return String.fromCharCode(num);
    })
    console.log(res);
</script>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't double the backslash characters; you can embed Unicode directly in JavaScript string constants.

Comment: Just write it as-is, without escaping. `console.log("Hello \u0028 Hi \u0029")` would work.

Comment: @RickyMo What if this is coming from external source already escaped?

Comment: You unescape it then. There is a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unescape-js) to do so

Comment: This is coming from external source so i cannot remove extra \, if it is already escaped from external source then no change.

Comment: Have you tried simply `JSON.parse()` on the source strings?

Comment: Yes using JSON.parse() it is working fine. Thank you